# iphone copying folder from bundle to documents

Tags: iphone, nsfilemanager, nsbundle

I'm having the hardest time getting this to work. I'm trying to copy a folder from my bundle to the documents directory.

the folder I'm trying to find is here:

...app/Resources/12/(a bunch of jpgs)

```
NSString *myPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"12"];
NSLog(@"%@",myPath);/// returns "..../MyApp.app/12"

NSArray *arrayOf12s = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:myPath error:nil];

NSLog(@"%@",arrayOf12s);     ////always returns NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the NSError argument in -contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:error: call?

```
NSString *myPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"12"];
NSLog(@"%@",myPath);/// returns "..../MyApp/12"

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *arrayOf12s = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:resourceDBFolderPath error:&error];

if (error)
   NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

NSLog(@"%@",arrayOf12s);     ////always returns NULL
```

It might shine some light on the cause...

Comment: All it gives is: Error: Operation could not be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)

Comment: What is 'resourceDBFolderPath' set to?

Comment: Also, have you seen this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418680/subdirectories-within-an-iphone-application>? It might help with including entire directory into your app bundle - as opposed to just the directory's contents.