# Deploy a file into iPad app Documents folder from Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

In my iPad Xcode project I have a file located inside Resources group folder. When deploying on iPad it goes to the Application folder  `...AFF9-8A934F9408B3/MyApp.app`, but I need it to go to `...AFF9-8A934F9408B3/Documents`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly place files into an application's document folder on the device as a part of the deployment. However, you can copy them from your (read only) bundle into the application's document folder.

To obtain a reference to an item in your bundle, you can use:

```
NSBundle *appBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *bundlePath = [appBundle pathForResource:@"XXXX" ofType:@"xxx"];
```

You can then load the data and save it as you would normally. There's more info on this process in the following question (amongst others): [iphone copying folder from bundle to documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053618/iphone-copying-folder-from-bundle-to-documents)