# Problem in copying a folder from resource to documents directory

Tags: iphone, nsfilemanager

I have a folder of images in the resource. I need to copy the entire folder in to the documents directory. Can any one pls help me with this?

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053618/iphone-copying-folder-from-bundle-to-documents) similar question