# How Do I Load A TableView With PPT Stored In MainBundle?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, nsarray, powerpoint

I am trying to load a TableView with powerpoint files that are stored in the MainBundle of my app.  I am having much difficulty.

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSArray *paths  = [bundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"ppt" inDirectory:@"Resources"];
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
self.title = @"Devo Songs";
self.files = [[[manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:paths error:nil] pathsMatchingExtensions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ppt", nil]] retain];
```

The app crashes and I get warnings on the last line stating incompatible pointer types sending NSArray to NSString.  How can I best go about loading the PPT files into a TableView?

Comment: You are getting that warning because `self.files` is `NSString` whereas the result is in an array, try using `objectAtIndex:0`just before your retain.

Comment: @iNoob That still is giving me the same error.  `self.files = [[[[manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:paths error:nil] pathsMatchingExtensions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ppt", nil]] objectAtIndex:0] retain];`  Error I get in console is `2012-04-08 23:15:58.329 AimTrue[53316:f803] -[__NSArrayM fileSystemRepresentation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x687f810
2012-04-08 23:15:58.332 AimTrue[53316:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM fileSystemRepresentation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: Can you just log your `NSArray *paths` ? Check if it is empty or not ?

Comment: I'm guessing that's why its crashing, can you try with a single power point file first like: `NSString*myPPtFile=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"yourPPTFile" ofType:@"ppt"];` ?

Comment: @iNoob Ok, tried that and my log for paths returned the location and filename of the power point file.  My code is now: `NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *paths  = [bundle pathForResource:@"SongTitle" ofType:@"ppt"];
    NSLog(@"%@", paths);
 NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
 self.title = @"Devo Songs";
 self.files = [[[manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:paths error:nil] pathsMatchingExtensions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ppt", nil]] retain];`
However, it still returns null for self.files count

Comment: Yes the array will return null, i've no idea on how to return an array for path in the bundle, i usually use single files to display, you can try having all the file names that you've added in an array, and use `[objectAtIndex]`  in `pathForResource:[yourArray objectAtIndex:0]`, i'm not sure how to get every filepath though.

Comment: I Will try searching on how to get the list of every element in the bundle.

Comment: Ok found one solution from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418680/subdirectories-within-an-ios-application, `pathForResourceOfType` works only on folders not groups, so the `inDirectory` should be a folder (which will be in blue color not yellow), so make sure the list of songs is in a folder for `pathForResourceOfType` to work not in a group.

Comment: This worked to finally get it...thanks for the link to adding folder and not group.  ` NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    
    NSArray *paths  = [bundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"ppt" inDirectory:@"powerpoint"];
    NSLog(@"%@", paths);
 self.title = @"Devo Songs";
 self.files = paths;`
The issue I now get is the cell.text displays the entire path of the .ppt and not just the file name.  What would be the best way to return that?

Comment: I know I could use 
 `NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

self.filenames = [[documentsDirectoryPath lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];`
But, that would only give me the first item in the TableView, and am having a hard time figuring out getting NSString to NSArray and everything.  Array can't do lastPathComponent, and NSString won't respond to indexPath.row, so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: You need to create a `NSMutableArray` object, and keep adding each `NSString` into that array, say if `paths` has 10 elements, you can do `for(int i=0;i<[paths count];i++) {NSString*someFileName=[paths objectAtIndex:i];
[yourMutableArray addObject:someFileName];
}

then you show this mutable array in your table's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. That will show the 10 elements of `paths` array

Comment: Saw that you already got an answer :D, good luck.