# How can one see an iOS bundle's file structure?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, bundle

I'm trying to create a subfolder structure in my app following this advice:

[Subdirectories within an iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418680/subdirectories-within-an-ios-application)

But I can't see (using the Organizer) a way to test whether the subfolder structure is actually achieved or not...is there a way to check, other than jailbreaking the phone and getting in through ssh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open the bundle that is installed to the simulator by navigating to:

```
<User Name>/Library/Application Support/iOS Simulator/<Alpha-Numeric String>/<App Name>.app'
```

Once you navigate to the above location (it may be .ipa, can't remember exactly) you can right click and choose `Show Package Contents` which will show you the contents app bundle.

Comment: My path was slightly different, with: `/Users/dpc/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/5.1/Applications/5` but the above was essentially correct, and I can now see subfolders within the app, thanks! This was using XCode Version 4.4 (4F250), and iOS Simulator Version 5.1 (272.21)

Comment: Glad you were able to get to the right direction. I'm not at my Mac so I was going off of memory.

Answer (score 2):

If the question relates to *.ipa or *.app boundles, then you can rename them to *.zip and go from there.

Comment: Unneccesary step on OS X. You can just right click a .ipa or .app and show the package contents.

Comment: good to know anyway though (illuminates that it's all zip), thanks Hermann.

Comment: Well, that is right in principle. Especially as most iOS developers would use a Mac or at least OS-X on some hardware. But really showing the content did not always work on my old iMac and knowing this trick was quite helpful sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, with Xcode 10 and macOS 10.14.X the path for simulators would be:

```
/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<XXX>/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/<YYY>
```

Also, if you want to check for the previous step and check the files that would be inside the *.app(bundle) in Derived Data (to check for devices) the path would be:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```